# Error in Installing Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have install Ruby on my machine. The version is 
ruby 1.9.3p551 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32].

Before, I was able to install Rails. But now, I've got an error that says,

```
$ gem install rails
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150226-5328-1diphe5.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make
Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.
2 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/extensions/x86-mingw32/1.9.1/js
on-1.8.2/gem_make.out
```

I cannot understand the error. Any response will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think issue is in version supporting.
You have installed ruby version `ruby 1.9.3p551` and when you try to install any `gem`  without version specification it takes latest version. So here rails may be try to install latest version `4.2` which is not supported to `ruby 1.9.3` [Check here : Ruby on Rails 4.0 Release Notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html)

> Ruby 2.0 preferred; 1.9.3+ required

Try to install rails with version specification which supported `ruby-1.9.3`, `Rails 3.2`

```
gem install rails --version '~> 3.2.0'
```

To check out Ruby and Rails version: run below command

```
ruby -v # return current ruby version
rails -v # return current rails version
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know
command :

```
 gem install rails
```

always looks for latest version of rails, and latest versions of rails doesn't support below ruby 2.

I can see you are using it on windows.

So, download [this](https://s3.amazonaws.com/railsinstaller/Windows/railsinstaller-3.1.0.exe) (it is an installer with ruby 2.1 and rails 4.1), it might resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gem install rails --version '~> 3.2.0'
```

Once successfully installed use `rails -v` to see installed rails version.